# Apply numpy broadcast_to on each vector in an array

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I want to apply something like this:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
np.broadcast_to(a, (3,3))

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

On each vector in a multi-vector array:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
np.broadcast_to(a, (2,3,3))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (2,3)  and requested shape (2,3,3)
```

To get something like this:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6]]])
```

Comment: You start with a (2,3) and want a (2,3,3), that is adding a new trailing dimension.  But by the rules of broadcasting, only new leading dimensions are automatic.  New trailing ones have to be explicit.  You can broadcast to (4,2,3), where the 4 is the new leading dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use list-comprehension and broadcast each of the inner array:

```py
>>> np.array([np.broadcast_to(i, (3,3)) for i in a])

array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],
       [[4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6]]])
```

Or, you can just add an extra dimension to `a` then call broadcast_to over it:

```py
>>> np.broadcast_to(a[:,None], (2,3,3))

array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],
       [[4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6]]])
```